# Can't get online after installing Lubuntu 15.04

Tags: network-manager, connection, 15.04

I upgraded to Lubuntu 15.04 yesterday. 
I originally installed Lubuntu at school several months back, so it was done using the school's Ethernet connection. At home, I set up my own DSL connection, which worked fine until yesterday. I needed only to click the DSL connection to get online.
Now, Ethernet connects (even though I can't use it at home), but DSL doesn't, even though the Network Connections haven't been altered by the upgrade.
The computer is an IBM R32-Thinkpad.
Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

To connect to PPPoE/DSL using NetworkManager on 15.04 requires installing the `pppoe` package, which was not installed by default on my Lubuntu 15.04.

```
sudo apt-get install pppoe
```

I've reported this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1455219

Answer (score -1):

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo pppoeconf
```

Enter your Ubuntu password.

If you don't know how to answer the questions it asks you, answer with *yes*. Then it will ask you the DSL username and DSL password.

Comment: Thanks me-clau27. But there's a problem. From "Open," I have opened both UXTerm and XTerm and typed in sudo pppoeconf - enter. Both then ask for my Lubuntu password, but there's no response to the keyboard from either when I try to key the password.

Comment: It's locked. I'll ask the one at school who helped me install it whether he used a particular password.

Comment: Strangely, the problem could only be solved by deleting my ADL details and then re-entering them (Add New).